# On Hom and Tensor evaluation of Coherent sheaves , two of which are Algebraic vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, schemes, coherent-sheaves, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a separated Noetherian scheme. Let $\mathcal E, \mathcal F, \mathcal G$ be coherent sheaves such that $\mathcal E, \mathcal F$ are algebraic vector-bundles (i.e. locally free coherent sheaves). Then, do the following isomorphisms hold:

(1) $$\mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal E, \mathcal G)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal F \cong \mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal E, \mathcal G\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal F)$$

(2) $$\mathcal E \otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal F,\mathcal G)\cong \mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal E, \mathcal F),\mathcal G) $$ ?

My motivation: I can prove both of these if $X$ is affine-scheme (in fact there I only need $\mathcal E$ to be vector-bundle i.e. I need it's global section module to be projective)

Comment: Yes these isomorphisms holds when $\mathcal{E}$ is a vector bundle.. In fact, the standard way to prove this is to construct a natural map between them. Then, to prove it is an isomorphism, you can prove it locally, that is when $\mathcal{E}$ is free.

Comment: @Roland: thank you ... I'll think about your comment